# Unclear about partition tables and copying full disk with dd

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, dd

I don't understand how dd treats partition tables when copying a full disk.

I backed up my whole disk (which had multiple partitions) using `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /media/notsdb/backfile.img.gz`

Now I have a brand new disk without a partition table that I want to put these partitions onto. The reverse command should be `gunzip -c /media/notsdb/backfile.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror bs=64K`.  Does this make sense and do I have to put a partition table onto the disk first?   (The operation takes 10 hours so I'd like to know before I do it)

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 2):

Copy it over, then use `gparted` (or similar) to resize / move partitions - `dd` will simply recreate the old partition scheme, as it is a bitwise copy & applies no 'intelligence' to the operation.

This only works if the new disk is the same size or larger!

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Williams says, the `dd` commands you've specified will replicate the old partition table, which you can then modify if necessary.

One caveat, though: If the disk uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) as most disks do on modern computers, the partition table is replicated at both the start and end of the disk. If the target disk is not *exactly* the same size as the original, the resulting restored disk may need minor repairs. IIRC, `parted`, GParted, and similar tools will notice if the new disk is bigger than the original and offer to make repairs. If you use my own GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, or `cgdisk`), you can manually repair the problem by typing `x` to go to the experts' menu, typing `e` to relocate the backup data structures to the end of the disk, and then typing `w` to save the changes.

If the new disk is *smaller* than the original, then the backup partition table on a GPT disk will be lost, necessitating a similar recovery procedure. Worse, on either a GPT disk or an MBR disk, the final partition (or even multiple partitions) might be damaged or lost entirely. There's nothing that can be done about this, really; at best, you'll be able to resize the final partition to fit and then do a filesystem repair (with `fsck`) to try to recover as much data as possible.

Note that these size issues can crop up even if the disks differ in size by even just a single sector. Disks marketed as being the same size (say, 2TB) may differ from each other in size by significantly more than that. If you plan to buy a replacement disk of the "same" size as the original, check the first original's size *accurate to the sector* and look up the technical specs on any potential replacement to be sure it's as large as or bigger than the original.